# Aggregate audio device can't record voice call

Tags: mac, audio, headphones, audio-recording, midi

I am using [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) on a Mac. Typically I wear headphones during a Zoom meeting or a voice call (like WeChat).  Wired or wireless headphones do not make any difference as far as I have tried.

In the Zoom case, I can easily record everything (others' and my own voices) with any headphones. I just create an aggregate audio device from Blackhole 2ch and the headphone's microphone and select it as the sound input in Mac's Midi setup. It then works well in both [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and QuickTimePlayer.

But in the voice call case, the same cannot record others' voices at all. What could be missing here?